# iOS publishing - Ionic 2

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, publishing

I followed [this guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) on publishing my ionic project.

Things changed a bit from Ionic 1, especially inside the portal of `Apple Developer Program` but using a bit of logic the steps are pretty much the same so I managed to go on until the point where I had to go to '`Product > Archive`'. 
Now, it's the first time for me working on iOS and I'm stuck here. 
Once I clicked 'Archive' the build failed and I got 3 error shown in the image:

[image]

**1.** `Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.`

Is it necessary? I don't even have any apple devices

**2.** `No profiles for 'myappname.it' were found: Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'myappname.it'.`

**3.** `Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'.`

I searched but couldn't solve anything. I don't understand what is the problem, could someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Have you set your bundle id correctly in the App -> Target -> General settings?

Comment: Well, I logged inside my Apple Developer portal and under _Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles_ > _Identifiers_ > _App IDs_ I clicked the one I created and there is the exact ID I have in Xcode

Comment: Have you also made the _Provisioning Profiles_ for Development and Distribution in the same menu? Also have you set it to generate profiles automatically in Xcode? [try this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)

Comment: As I said i'm not an expert on this argument but I followed the guide. I enrolled the Apple Developer program and paid the $99 for one year. Then I went to Xcode to Preferences -> Accounts and added my account. I clicked the '+' and the View details on the one with '(Personal Team) that has 'User' below 'Role' . But the 'create' button next to iOS distribution wasn't enabled so I waited. The day after I went to accounts and there was another one with 'Role -> Agent', I clicked 'view details' and then the 'create' button of 'ios distribution'. I uploeaded another image of my general settings

Comment: Ok, then if you go to Apple Developer portal and click on _Provisioning Profiles_, do you see 2 certificates with your bundle id, one for development and one for distribution?

Comment: Once you generate the certificates in Apple Developer Portal, you must download both of them and double click to install them in your Xcode. Alternatively, you can go to Xcode -> Prefrences -> Account -> (click on your account) -> View Details (bottom right) and then press create next to provision profiles for development and distribution. (You can then click download all, on the bottom left and wait a few seconds and try building again).

Comment: Also, in the team dropdown that you just uploaded, do you see another option? Perhaps the email you used to sign up for apple's dev program?

Comment: It's a bit strange. I went to Apple Dev. portal and under _Provisioning Profiles_ there's only one certificate as iOS Distribution type. If I go to _Certificates_ instead there are two of them: the one with iOS Development is named _Name Surname (Name's Mac)_

Comment: Please make another certificate under provisioning profile for _iOS Development_. I think thats why it's unable to generate the profile. Click on **+** and then on _iOS App Development_, click continue and then select your bundle id for the app. Once generated, download, double click and run it.

Comment: It redirects me to device: _No Devices are available.
Click "Create Devices." to create a Device. You need a Device to configure a Provisioning Profile._

Comment: Yes, thats good. Create a profile for your device. Do you have one?

Comment: No, I don't own any apple devices. I mentioned that in the question. But am I forced to have one in order to publish an iOS app made with ionic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137803/discussion-between-return0-and-pier).